# How to reset menu item hover colour in JavaFX after the mouse leaves the item?

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I created a **Java FXML file** and included **Css styling** to create a window as shown below:

[image: Application Screenshot]

This is my CSS Stylesheet

```
.button {
-fx-background-color:transparent;
-fx-background-radius:0;
-fx-border-color:transparent;
-fx-border-width:0;
}

.button:focused {
-fx-background:transparent;
-fx-background-radius:0;
-fx-border-color:transparent;
-fx-border-width:0;
}

.button:hover {
-fx-background-color:transparent, red ,red, red;
-fx-background-radius:0;
-fx-border-width:0;
}

.button:pressed {
-fx-background-color:#DD2C00;
}

.menu {
-fx-padding:1 10 1 5;
}

.menu .context-menu {
-fx-padding:1 1 1 1;
}

.menu-bar {
-fx-background-color:#212121;
-fx-padding:0 1 0 1;
-fx-spacing:1;
}

.menu-bar .label {
-fx-padding:0 10 0 10;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button {
-fx-background-color:#212121;
-fx-padding:5 5 5 5;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button > .label {
-fx-text-fill:#E0E0E0;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button > .label:disabled,.menu-item .label:disabled {
-fx-opacity:1.0;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button:hover > .label,.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button:focused > .label {
-fx-text-fill:#FFF;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button:hover,.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button:focused {
-fx-background-color:#424242;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button:showing > .label,.menu-item .label {
-fx-text-fill:#000;
}

.menu-bar > .container > .menu-button:showing,.context-menu {
-fx-background-color:#FFF;
}

.menu-item {
-fx-background-color:#FFF;
-fx-padding:5 20 5 20;
}

.menu-item:focused .label,.menu-item:hovered .label {
-fx-text-fill:#EaE3EA;
}

.menu-item:focused,.menu-item:hovered {
-fx-background-color:#1565C0;
}
.menu-item:left {
    -fx-background-color: #FFF;
}
.root {
-fx-font-family:"Segoe UI";
-fx-font-weight:bold;
-fx-smooth:true;
}
```

The problem is that when I leave my mouse from a menu item,

> it still stays blue and doesn't change back to white.

[image: Top: Before Hover, Bottom: During and after Hover]

Hoping that someone with the knowledge and experience of designing JavaFX menus can guide me to achieve the results.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because it's too early in the morning to think straight but I think you have unnecessary CSS rules in your file. In any case, use the rules below (in addition to yours ):

```
.menu-item {
   -fx-background-color: white;
   -fx-padding: 5 20 5 20;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-focus-color;
}
```

I left the `-fx-padding` from your css rules. The above just sets the background color of each menu item to be white and on :hover rule i am setting it back the default selection color `#039ED3` which is the same as writing `-fx-focus-color`.